# Accessing Android JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I'm downloading a JSON file with the structure:

```
    {
        "options": {
        "toolbar": "1",
        "full": "1",
        "exit": "0",
        "about": "0"
    },
   "general": {
     "versioncontrol": "1.0"
   },
  "companydetails": {
    "toolbaricons": {
      "1": [
        "Facebook",
        "xxx",
        "xxx"
      ],
      "2": [
        "Instagram",
        "xxx",
        "xxx"
      ],
      "3": [
        "LinkedIn",
        "xxx",
        "xxx"
      ]
    },
    "buttons": "4",
    "openingtimes": {
      "1": "10:00 - 16:00",
      "2": "9:00 - 16:00"
    }
  }
}
```

I've managed to extract it from the server as a string which I am now storing in a variable.

I've tried

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(fileOutput);
JSONArray details = jsonObj.getJSONArray("options");
JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(0);
```

But I cannot seem to extract anything from it. I want to be able to access all different bits in options etc and gather the information. I've tried to print to log the details of options etc, but I can't seem to get it to work. I had it working before but now the file structure has been updated and the old method I was using no longer works.

Comment: Options is not array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options is not array but object, use:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(fileOutput);
JSONObject options = jsonObj.getJSONObject("options");
int toolbar = options.getInt("toolbar");
```

Comment: Thanks - This pointed me in the right direction, knew I was slightly wrong somewhere